# How I can commit and push a project that the name is renewed?

Tags: xcode, git

I changed my existing project name to new one.
After that I tried to commit this project to push my github repo.
However with the error you can see on my attached image file,
I got an error.

I think Xcode can't find the directory of the project.

How I can handle this error?
[image]
Thank you so much!

Comment: Change it back?

Comment: Thank you Joakim! Actually I solved this question with 'fetch file status'!